# Client-side validation using a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, validation, client-side-validation

I Have some basic Requirement like

- Should Validate Form on the ButtonClick (like we have ValidationGroup in Asp.net) because I have one
- Submit Button on Page (btnSubmit)
- Cancel Button ( If user Click on Cancel Button .. No validation Should be checked and user will return to "Home.aspx" )
- One More Submit Button on Page (btnSubmit2) but this button can be seen if user Fill Up another form using Dialogue Box
- Should Show LiveChanges (Supoose I entered Invalid EmailID and I moved to Next InputField .. it should Display errorMessage.. If I go back to and Corrected the same then error message should disappear)

Which Plugin will fullfill above Requirement

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking for a plugin recommendation are clearly off-topic.  See item 4:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jqueryvalidate is a great plugin that fullfills you needs: http://jqueryvalidation.org/